# Error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in

Tags: php

I keep on getting this error

> Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in ..on line 134.

**database.php**

```
require_once("connect.php");

class Database {
    private $connect;

    function one() {
        $connectdb = $this->connect;
        $forms = new Forms();
        $forms->two();
    }
}
```

**forms.php**

```
require_once("connect.php");

class Forms {
    private $connect;

    function two() {
        $connectdb = $this->connect;

        $construct = $connectdb->prepare("SELECT child.*, parent.name as pname, parent.information as pinformation
            FROM strings child LEFT JOIN strings parent on child.pageid=parent.id WHERE child.sid=:id AND child.submittype='2'");
        $executequery = $construct->execute(array(':id'=>$id));
    }

}
```

The error happens on the line with the query.  My guess is something to do with the private variable `$connect`.  How do I solve this?

Comment: If don't see `$this->connect` being _set_ to something useful anywhere?

Comment: How is $this->connect set in your Forms class?

Comment: Is `$connect` a **PDO** object ?

Comment: change
**`private $connect;`**
to
**`private $connect=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb;charset=latin1;','user','pass');`**

Answer (score 0):

you need to instantiate first a new object of the Class `Database` and assign it to `$connect`:

```
$this->connect = new Database();
```

and then you might use it:

```
$connectdb = $this->connect;
```

Answer (score 0):

Connect in your Forms class is not a database connector.

```
class Forms {
    private $connect;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->connect = Database::getConnection(); // we will define this method below
    }

    function two() {
        $connectdb = $this->connect;

        $construct = $connectdb->prepare("....query....");
        $executequery = $construct->execute(array(':id'=>$id));
    }

}
```

The database connector:

```
class Database {
    private static $connect;

    public static function getConnection(){
        if (self::$connect){
            return self:$connect;
        }
        self::$connect = new mysqli(...) or what ever connection u use

    }
}
```